# Android Studio: Re-download dependencies and sync project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I downloaded an open source game "[ChaseWhisplyProject](https://github.com/tvbarthel/ChaseWhisplyProject)" source code from Github.

I imported the project in my Android Studio (Version 1.5.1).

It shows following error message:

Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

I changed all the dependency versions to latest one bu still it is showing the same message.

It has two modules under the main project 1) BaseGameUtils & 2)ChaseWhisply.
The above modules are not shown in bold letters (I think it should be shown in bold letters like module "app").

Following are the gradle files.

1) Root Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to         all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}
```

2) BaseGameUtils Module Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

3) ChaseWhisply Module Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    lintOptions {
        // TODO fix and remove !
        disable 'MissingTranslation', 'DuplicateIds', 'ExtraTranslation'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 22
        versionName "0.3.6"
    }
}
```

4) Settings.gradle

```
include ':ChaseWhisply', ':BaseGameUtils'
```

What is wrong over here? Please help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

While importing a libGDX project I got the same message from Android Studio 2.2.

Went to *File->Project Structure* then selected *Project* and set

**Gradle version**

and

**Android Plugin Version**

to values identical to another project I had recently created with Android Studio 2.2 and updated SDK. Could then sync gradle.  Did *Build->Build Clean* with no issues. Then did *Run->Clean and Rerun* and project ran fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 26):

It basically means that the **gradle** zip file in the cache folder is corrupted, if you don't want to change the version like the `up-voted` answer then you must delete the folder for your **gradle** **version** you're using for this project from the below path.

Then just retry the sync and `android studio` will download it again

```
C:\Users\ [user here]  \.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

ex: if you're using 3.3 for this project you'd be deleting the folder

```
C:\Users\[user here]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all
```

Comment: This answer is spot-on with my situation. The zip file was downloaded only partially, and clicking redownload in AS did nothing. I had to go in and delete the corrupt gradle distribution, *then* click redownload.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue. The solution worked for me was go to "gradle\wrapper\dists" and deleted the folder "grade-4.10.1-all" folder and downloaded the same version after that i pasted the extracted folder in same address.After that I again synchronized the android studio. I worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem and I search for it and found a best solution and i works for me:

1. Manually download Gradle 3.3 binary (direct link: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip)
2. Open your android studio root directory, and extract the zip to the gradle folder (for example: program files/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.3)
3. Open Android Studio, go to File->Settings-> (Build, Exectution, Deployment) >Gradle and set "Gradle home" to point your new gradle-3.3 folder.
4. Apply and sync.

Answer (score 1):

May be incompatible with Gradle and maven version
delete project dir/gradle/wrapper 
put a right version gradle into it 
run again

Answer (score 1):

change the gradle-wraper-properties distributionUrl to your local downloaded gradle such as

**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by this following steps

1.C:\Users\System name.gradle\wrapper\

2.Inside wrapper folder u will find grale file with some version, You just have to delete it

3.Come/Go to android studio and Go to File->Sync project with Gradle Files.

4.Android studio automatically download the require gradle file.

5.And now go for coding

Answer (score 1):

[image: delete from this directory folder]

The close android studio then goes to the directory and you will find this type of folder. I saw in my pc. after deleted then clean project and sync. its works fine.

you just delete from this directory
C:\Users\ [user here]  .gradle\wrapper\dists

if you use 3.3 version in android studio. you can see like this
C:\Users[user here].gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's a bit late, but usually happens when something went wrong in Android Studio's initial launch (eg. system crash, connection loss or whatever). We can call it bad programming or lazy QA.

To fix this close Android Studio and delete everything from the following directory. Don't worry files will be downloaded on next launch.

**For Windows: C:\Users\your-username.gradle\wrapper\dists**

**For Linux: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists**

**For mac: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists**

You can also Gradle manually to fix this issue, But it's better to let Android studio does this work. .

Answer (score 0):

Clean Project is a way to go. After you clean project, make sure you rebuild it. Usually it solves the gradle issues for me.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this problem too.  Clean Project actually fails for me with the same error message as mentioned in the question post.  I suspect that some file needs to be deleted before this message goes away.   Unfortunately the IDE gives little clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: @Wossname did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MidasLefko, no I'm sorry to say.  I gave up on android in the end, life's too short to fight endlessly with low quality dev tools. :( (hehe and yes I am blaming my tools as all bad workmen tend to do).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running IntelliJ IDEA as non root user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the new features, you should not revert it to the old version, just delete the directory ~/.gradle recursively, then restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle version and update with required version of gradle and syn your project.

https://services.gradle.org/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, open your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file from the project then note down the version of the Gradle.

It could be like this:

```
distributional=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

So, here my Gradle version is `6.5`. It could be different in your case.

After this, open file explorer and open your project folder. There you will be having the Gradle folder open it, inside it the version will be mentioned of your previous Gradle.

Now you will have to download the Gradle file according to the wrapper.properties(for example nothing but `6.5` version).

You can download it from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

- Extract it
- paste it to the Gradle folder
- open your project > file > settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle, then select the newly downloaded Gradle file in the Gradle user home.

Then run your project.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - go to https://gradle.org/releases/ and download latest stable version (binary-only works fine). extract and insert into `C:\Users\OWNER\.gradle\wrapper\dists` folder.
Open Android Studio settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle, use gradle from: specific location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved my problem :

1.C:\Users\System name.gradle\wrapper\

2.Inside wrapper folder u will find grale file with some version, You just have to delete it

3.Come/Go to android studio and Go to File->Sync project with Gradle Files.

4.Android studio automatically download the require gradle file.

5.And now go for coding