# Plugin with id 'gwt' not found

Tags: java, android-studio, gwt, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

**Building libgdx project**

First time i got error `re-download dependencies and sync project` each time i build my project. Then i got the solution from this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101206/android-studio-re-download-dependencies-and-sync-project/39821915#39821915) 
I did change the following from as instructed from the post

```
file -> project structure -> project
```

i. gradle version from 3.3 to 2.14.1

ii. update android studio plugin to 2.2.3 (*it was unset*)

I did take the values from recent working android project

My `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.14.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'FirstDemo'
        gdxVersion = '1.6.4'
        roboVMVersion = '1.14.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.4.0'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Now i am getting error "Plugin with id 'gwt' not found". Can someone please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this dependency into your buildscript tag of your root build.gradle file

```
classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
```

After addition your buildscript looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.14.0'
    }
}
```