# Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39821915/5188159

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt)

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801113/7120475

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304945/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network/54305292#54305292

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the same issue when I updated my android studio to 2.2.3 from 2.1. After a while of struggling, went project->right click -> open module settings->project

1) Gradle : 2.14.1
2) Android plugin version : 2.2.3
3) Android plugin repository : jcenter
4) Default library repository : jcenter

Comment: @Mahesh Kumthekar you can also check this out [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/features.html) for features.

Comment: Yes sure @Android Dev

Comment: Cool answer, my two cents: It does change **distributionUrl** inside `your_project -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: gradle has advanced since.. it's now version 3.3 which fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

## Repair Gradle Installation

(From my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801113/7120475)

This usually happens when something goes wrong in Android Studio's first launch (eg. system crash, connection loss or whatever).

To resolve this issue close Android Studio and delete the following directory's content, necessary files **will be downloaded on IDE's next launch.**

**macOS:** `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

**Windows:** `C:\Users\your-username\.gradle\wrapper\dists`

While downloading Gradle manually works, I recommend letting Android Studio itself to do it.

Comment: Thanks Hamid :) for fixing "Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)" your answer is the perfect solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey not necessary to set gradle manually. i have also faced this issue but i deleted all files in gradle folder path "C:/Users/username/.gradle/" simple steps follow

1. first goto path "C:/Users/MickeyMouse/.gradle/"
2. delete all files in above path.
3. List item open android studio and sync gradle or build again or
   create new project.
4. List item it will be auto downloaded new gradle version
   files and auto build.

***Make sure you your gradle settings like this - checked "Use default gradle** wrapper(recommended) - unchecked offline work

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked after I added my NDK path in Android Studio.

File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Android NDK Location

Answer (score 0):

Hard and fast solution for MacOS (and possibly Linux)

1. Go to ~/.gradle
2. Delete all files:   rm -rf .gradle
3. Go to your project folder and do :  ./gradlew bootRun

The last step should download all gradle dependencies again.