# Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, error-handling, sdk

I updated android studio 2.3 and there is a bug, gradle doesn't build and it keeps giving me the same error for all projects.

```
Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
```

I have already searched for a solution, but have not found any. I tried:

```
Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

but nothing has changed.

Comment: Answer by Hamid Asghari is better solution

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**UPDATE 17 JULY 2018:**

Even if the following solution still works as of today,I've found (thanks to the answer posted by Hamid Asghari and to the comment posted by Mahendra Dabi) that simply deleting the gradle dist directory and performing a reboot of the ide, will fix the issue (please read Hamid post for a full answer, and remember that OSX and Linux have the same gradle path).

If you still want to follow my original solution, you should at least consider using a more up-to-date version of Gradle (direct link of the gradle distribution repo: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

---

**Original answer (dated 7 March 2017):**

I've faced the same issue this morning after upgrading Android Studio to 2.3.
To solve the issue:

1) Manually download Gradle 3.3 binary (direct link: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip)

2) Open your android studio root directory, and extract the zip to the gradle folder (for example in my Debian machine the full path is /opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.3)

3) Open Android Studio, go to File->Settings->Build, Exectution, Deployment->Gradle and set "Gradle home" to point your new gradle-3.3 folder.

4) Sync and you are ready to go!

Comment: erasing the dist folders will get everything in shape

Comment: delete the content of following directory:                                             
 macOS: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists
Windows: C:\Users\your-username\.gradle\wrapper\dists

Comment: if the "Gradle home" button is disabled, then you can check the "use local gradle distribution" radio button above the "Gradle home"

Comment: @Hamid Asghari what should I do then? You tell me. I can edit the "update" if you wish. EDIT: I've edited the "update" to make you happy.

Comment: Go to "File" in android studio, Click "invalidate caches/Restart" and "Invalidate and Restart"
That also works

Answer (score 225):

## Repair Gradle Installation

This usually happens when something goes wrong in Android Studio's first launch (eg. system crash, connection loss or whatever).

To resolve this issue close Android Studio and delete the following directory's content, necessary files **will be downloaded on IDE's next launch.**

**macOS:** `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

**Linux:** `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

**Windows:** `C:\Users\your-username\.gradle\wrapper\dists`

While downloading Gradle manually works, I recommend letting Android Studio do the work for you.

Comment: better solution . and recommended way

Comment: You may be having different projects on different gradle build. So delete only that directory from dist.
eg. I had problem with gradle-4.6-all, so i deleted only dists/gradle-4.6-all/

Comment: This is the solution to fix this issue and it is well explained.

Comment: I can't find dists file inside .gradle/wrapper

Comment: Deleted on windows like you said. Did not download on next ide boot.

Answer (score 49):

I faced the same issue 2 days ago and today I was able to solve it like this:

1. Go to this path `C:\Users\user_name\.gradle\wrapper\dists` where `user_name` is your username if its you own PC or your company's name.
2. Delete the latest `gradle-****-all` files since your latest update of android studio (ex. 2.3 or another version).
3. If your android studio is open, close it then reopen it. A newer Gradle version will be downloaded, it will take time depending on your internet speed, the download size is around 150-200 MB before extraction so if android studio takes a long time to refresh just know its downloading. (To check the download progress right click on the new gradle folder, go to properties and check the size).

Answer (score 37):

Find 'gradle-wrapper.properties' in root project

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Change "https" to "http".

Comment: I have not tried downloading the gradle manually but I have tried deleting the 'dists' folder but it is not working. This answer works for me tho.

Comment: Have you set a proxy?

Comment: in my case it was older version issue

Answer (score 19):

**There are Following Steps to solve this issue.**

---

1. Go to *C:\Users\ ~User Name~ \.gradle\wrapper\dists*. 

2. Delete all the files and folders from dists folder.

3. If Android Studio is Opened then Close any opened project and Reopen the project. The Android Studio Will automatic download all the required files.

(The required time is as per your Internet Speed (Download Size will be about "89 MB"). To see the progress of the downloading Go to *C:\Users\  ~User Name~ \.gradle\wrapper\dists* folder and check the size of the folder.)

Answer (score 11):

just remove and reDownload wrapper gradle.

**Mac** Home/.gradle/wrapper/dists/

remove gradle version and sync gradle in project and run project.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Go to Project pane> Android > Gradle Scripts and open "graddle-wrapper.properties" file check the distribution URL:

[image]

Go to your ".gradle/wrapper/dists/" folder and remove that file for me it was "gradle-5.6.4-all"

[image]

Then go back to android studio and click on File > Sync Project with Gradle Files. And it will start to download again

[image]

Comment: this should be the selected answer as it solves probems with all other projects that use the same version of gradle

Comment: this is the best answer. just follow it.

Answer (score 5):

****Following solution is working for me****
Manually deleted all files from C:\Users\Admin.gradle\wrapper\dists\

where Admin is my user name

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio 4.1.1 has this bug,

In gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

This won't download and always gives 'gradle cache corrupt' error, but a small change makes it work fine

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Now sync the gradle again and it's done.

Answer (score 3):

1.Go to "/Users/****/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-**.**-all/*****".

2.Delete the "gradle-**.**-all.zip.lck" file.

3.Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need to clean all files in dir 
`C:\Users\ ~User Name~ \.gradle\wrapper\dists`.
and download all of them again

instead you can just delete the folder of gradle version you failed to download. In my case it was gradle-4.4-all so i just deleted that folder and android studio re downloaded gradle-4.4-all for me

In case you don't know version you was downloading:

Just go to help menu > show logs in explorer

> their you will find idea.log open it and search for

```
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distribution`
```

once you find it you will find gradle version you failed to download

Answer (score 1):

This was the best solution for me, just follow this path C:\Users\yourusername.gradle\wrapper\dists then delete all the files inside this folder. Close your android studio and restart it and it will automatically download the updated gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading gradle from 4.1 to 4.10 and my internet connection timed out.

So I fixed this issue by deleting "gradle-4.10-all" folder in .gradle/wrapper/dists

Answer (score 1):

Taking a cue from @Mikel Yang, I found out that instead of deleting the ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/ folder (which will means downloading the gradle files for different apps on my Android Studio), I decided to change the gradle.wrapper.properties file to any **latest** gradle --all.zip. So

```
Find 'gradle-wrapper.properties' in root project

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{lastest}-all.zip
```

this way l get to save some data and time.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because of a partially downloaded gradle distribution zip

- To resolve simply go to below path

  "C:/Users/your_username/.gradle"

  OR

  pull your gradle path from 
  File->Settings->Build, Exectution, Deployment-> Gradle -> gradle service directory path.
- Delete the partially downloaded distribution gradle folder
- Go to Studio (no need to restart) and perform gradle sync

Answer (score 1):

Go to "File" in android studio, Click "invalidate caches/Restart" and "Invalidate and Restart"

That also works

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue, In my understanding, It is because of invalid combination of **Android Studio And Gradle Plugin versions**. I was using Gradle version 5.4.1 and Studio version 3.4, hence I updated the Android studio to 3.5 and the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the latest gradle-*.*-all folder from the below path
Windows: C:\Users\your-username.gradle\wrapper\dists

Answer (score 0):

> find file gradle-wrapper.properties

update with :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

1). Android studio-> file-> "Invalidate Caches/Restart" -> "Invalidate and Restart"

```
wait for gradle sync
```

2). Download gradle.x.x.x-bin.zip using browser

```
unzip it and place it in ".gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-x.x.x-bin\xxxxxxxxxxx(auto generated folder)/
```

then restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply rename "Gradle" folder to "Gradle-OLD" in your project, then restart Android Studio. The system will generate a new Gradle folder.
It worked for me on Mac-os.