# Error: Failed to open zip file

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I just updated my Android Studio to the latest version and I am getting this error when opening a project:

```
Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a 
network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
```

I tried rebuild the project but it is not working as of now. My network connection is fine. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you see any specific dependency which is corrupted in _Gradle Console_ or _Build tab_?

Comment: this is all i get in the error log thats why i am asking in stack

Comment: see this hope it help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654435/9130109