# How to change default gradle home path for Android-Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 with default gradle version 4.1 on windows
but every time I start new project I have to change gradle home path as following image

[image: use local gradle distribution]

my question is how I can make this path the default path for all new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed with follwing steps

> This usually happens when something goes wrong in Android Studio's
>   first launch (eg. system crash, connection loss or whatever).
>
> To resolve this issue close Android Studio and delete the following
>   directory's content, necessary files will be downloaded on IDE's next
>   launch.
>
> macOS: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists
>
> Windows: C:\Users\your-username.gradle\wrapper\dists
>
> While downloading Gradle manually works, I recommend letting Android
>   Studio itself to do it.

got the answer from here 
[Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt)

Comment: This is valid to fix download problems, but doesn't address the OP question: how to set a default Gradle location for new Android Studio projects.