# Android studio Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt, not loading

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Whenever I create a new project or open the exciting one, **gradle** not building shows me this error

```
Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
```

Then I change **distributionUrl** from https to http and perform **Invalidate Caches / Restart**, Gradle starts building.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you are connected to the network.

Then open Android Studio and execute a clean and a rebuild task.

Try syncing gradle using the refresh button located at the top-right of the window more than once time, retry to invalidate cache/restart.

Be sure you added google() and maven() in your repositories -> build.gradle (project level).

If any of that tasks succeded try to delete your .android hidden folder, located at your installation path.

UPDATE:
Try to go in your .gradle hidden folder then navigate to wrapper folder and delete the dists folder. Then restarts your ide.

You can refer to this question for more details: [Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt)

Comment: Nothing works
Still have to do Invalidate cache/restart.

Comment: Actually the issue is whenever I create new project this happens

Comment: Probably you have damaged libs in gradle/wrapper/dists. Delete the folder and restrt your IDE

Comment: Did it but same

Comment: Try to add manually a dist of gradle in dists folder then go in android studio and link the gradle home to your folder. You can download gradle from here [gradle distributions](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Comment: Thank and sorry for not accepted this answer earlier