# Android Studio gradle build failed for hello world app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVT2l.png)I installed android studio 3.2.1 and tried to create a simple hello world app. But don't know why it gives error:

Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Though I have a proper internet connection.

Comment: Try Open File > Sync project with Gradle files. or File > Invalidate/caches restart,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt)

Answer (score 3):

Try this solutions:

1. **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...**
2. **Build > Clean Project** then **Run**
3. `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`
4. Close Android Studio => Remove gradle **caches folder** => Open Android Studio then gradle will try to download and fix dependencies.

   - **For Windows:** open this path and delete caches folder.

     ```
     C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\caches
     ```
   - **For Unix systems:**

     ```
     rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
     ```

Answer (score 2):

codeplay, first off I'd like to say welcome to stack overflow! I firmly believe that people who take the time to ask good questions on this site really go places in with their code. I got the same issue, and honestly can't remember exactly what I did to fix it, but I recommend looking at your SDK settings and reading up on gradle. It's time well spent https://developer.android.com/studio/build/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
Few points you can verify :-

1.It may be your internet connection issue so check your internet connection is working well.

2.This can be solve by Perform invalidate cache/ Restart

3.If above 2 options are not wokring you need to reload the the dependencies so perform rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/ and ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies perfom these both commands and reverify your gradle path. This may solve your problem.