# URI is not registered error. beginner at android studio

Tags: android

I'm new to the android studio. When I downloaded it first it worked all fine but then suddenly it started showing this error. I reinstalled it but still, the error is there.

[image: Error image]

Comment: check this answer here  might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801113/7200713

Comment: did not help. still facing the problem. i tried fetching external resources but its showing error in that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error log at the bottom right of your Android Studio telling you that:

```
Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
```

this means that your Gradle or Gradle dependency file is corrupted. You need to try removing the `.gradle` directory in your project then try build the application. If the problem still persist, you need to remove/renaming the related gradle binary from your cache. For Linux system (My system is Slackware, so it may vary with the other linux), it usually inside:

```
/home/username/.gradle/wrapper/dists/
```