# Change Gradle version from 4.6 to 4.10.1 cause sync failed invalid

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my Gradle version from 4.6 to 4.10.1 but I am getting an error

> "Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.6."

I have manually updated the grade version of `cache.properties` and deleted 4.6 related folders under `.gradle` dir but still same problem.

My `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
}
```

And `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2[![enter image description here][1]][1]-all.zip
```

Added Screenshot
 [image]

Comment: Have you synchronized your project?

Comment: Interesting, perhaps run `gradlew` and synchronize?

Comment: yes, And Android Studio shows "Synchronize <Project> completed successfully '

Comment: After running the gradlew command, I am getting the same error message

Comment: see [android studio gradle versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464)

Comment: Have you tried to restart `Android Studio`?

Comment: many times I restarted AS

Answer (score 2):

- Try **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** and
- Check **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Project**. 
  The Gradle version should be `4.10.1` and the plugin version should be `3.3.2` for your case. See:

  [image]

Also, try to run build from command line using gradle wrapper `gradlew`, e.g.

```
./gradlew assemble
```

See: [What is real Android Studio Gradle Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464)

Answer (score 1):

Check your Android Studio preferences for does it use default gradle wrapper.

Comment: it is set as default Gradle wrapper. however still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Just Sharing how I fixed this problem.

- Followed [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801113/6594057) by [Hamid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7120475/hamid-asghari)

> To resolve this issue close Android Studio and delete the following
>   directory's content, necessary files will be downloaded on IDE's next
>   launch.
>
> macOS: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists
>
> Linux: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists
>
> Windows: C:\Users\your-username.gradle\wrapper\dists

- Restarted Android Studio and it worked like a charm.

Comment: this is my distribution URL in Gradle wrapper distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip  but AS downoading gradle 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Go the project location and open terminal that location and do the following command 
First  ./gradlew clean 
Then  ./gradlew assembleDebug

N.B. Make sure you are connected to internet