# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error on windows system. Unable to sync. Already tried invalidate cache and restart. The log also shows

Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Here add google maven repository link not at all works

gradle-wrapper properties file

```
  #Thu Jan 07 16:53:17 IST 2021
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Comment: Add project level gradle with question

Comment: This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671508/9701793) for your issue.

Comment: Its not working. same error I am gettimg