# Gradle error : unable to open zip file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I open Project it will give error:

> Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be
>   corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

I tried this:
[Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789809/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradle-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-some)

but not working for me.

this is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.web"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
      compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
```

**Top Level Build File** (Project Level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        flatDir {
            dirs "${rootDir}/libs"
        }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run `gradlew --refresh-dependencies clean build` from the command line?

Comment: it is downloading 2.14.1 zip. but i have already added to project module setting

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network

Comment: i also do invalidate and restart.. not working for me.

Comment: @JJG Can you please post the other project level `build.gradle` and the `gradle-wrapper.properties`? Thanks

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Added Project Level File.. and also update the API Of My Project Still Same Error.

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: @JJG can you please check your libs folder is there any `zip` file

Comment: Have you tried to clean (remove) `C:\Users\<>\.gradle\caches`?

Comment: @Eselfar gradle version  3.3.

Comment: @Kaushik I Have YoutubePlayer Lib

Comment: @JJG can you please download youtube player from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/). One zip folder will be downloaded after extracting that zip you can find the `jar` inside libs folder. Please copy that `.jar` file into your libs folder and delete the `.zip` file from your project's libs folder.

Comment: @Kaushik tried. Still Same Problem. I dont think so youtube Player Make any issue.. because i already Used In Other App.. thanks for efforts.

Answer (score 1):

### According to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt):

> - Close Android Studio.
> - Download Gradle 3.3 binary from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
> - Extract the downloaded zip file to the gradle folder:
>
>   ```
>     C:\Users\user-name\.gradle\wrapper\dists\
>   ```
> - Now open the Android Studio, go to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd> -> <kbd>Gradle</kbd> and set **Gradle Home** to the folder gradle-3.3 and SYNC.

### OR

> - Close Android Studio.
> - And delete all the files under this directory:
>
>   ```
>     C:\Users\user-name\.gradle\wrapper\dists\
>   ```
> - Now open the Android Studio and the necessary files will be downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I too had same sort of issue. Try this:

```
Tools--> Android--> Sync Project With Gradle Files
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue sometime ago, I found simple workaround for it.

```
File ->Invalidate Caches/ Restart -> Select Invalidate and Restart option.
```

It will clear all local history and restart automatically. All necessary files will be downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly close the android studio
then remove all files from /dist folder

**C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists**

basically, this folder contains gradle

after that open android studio. clear project and build it.

Comment: How this solution is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48060873/4816207) one