# How to fix "Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt" error after updating android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3?

Tags: android

[image]

```
> Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be
> corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) <a
> href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
> network)</a> <a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync
> project (requires network)</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean project, build -> clean

Comment: just click on the error message that says **re-download...** and wait until it finishes downloading and installing. and while doing so make sure you have a stable network connection

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit i do this but he field .... and i dont what i do

Comment: I have  2.2.3 to 2.3 updating error. I installed the Android  Studio 2.3 again.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit I tried what you said but it does nothing...

Comment: OK. One thing you can try is delete all the files from cache folder of gradle. and then when you try to rebuild your project android studio will prompt you to install the dependencies again. path for the cache folder: **home/.gradle/caches/** .P.S: It's hidden by default.

Comment: In these situations File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart... --> Invalidate and Restart works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt)

Comment: The answer is in the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205838/7663327

Answer (score 37):

Find 'gradle-wrapper.properties' in root project

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Change "https" to "http".

pls see the picture.[image]

Comment: Thanks , Worked for me , just replace https to http

Comment: but what are the implications? This seems more like a hack since we are compromising on SSL end point

Comment: thanks perfect fix... but it is unfortunate that the default blank activity app has this issue...

Comment: In my case `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-all.zip` was throwing the same error posted in the question. Now with `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-all.zip` it says `Gradle Sync: Download http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-all.zip`. It looks like it is fixing it for me too.

Comment: I tried this steps In android studio 3.6.1 but it failed with: 7:38 PM Gradle sync failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Comment: Instead of changing the protocol, you can add a "?" at the end of the URL and AS will download everything again, like this: "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip?"

Answer (score 15):

go to the "home.gradle\wrapper\dists" folder and cut/delete the "gradle-3.3-all" folder, now rebulid the project. This should resolve the issue, as it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I face this problem after updating Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3;

**Solution**

1) In your project open 'gradle-wrapper.properties', change the 'distributionUrl' value

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

2) In you project open the project's 'build.gradle' file, and change the classpath

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

3) At last Sync your project.

(This is the latest gradle setting.)

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1** 
Go to your dir (cd ~) and do ls -la , It will show you .gradle folder.
Do cd .gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all and check it premission

provide full permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .gradle/
```

it will provide full permision to .gradle folder

**Step 2**
delete the previous one

```
rm -rf .gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/
```

**Step 3** 
Use Restart and invalidate option of Android Studio
it will clear previous cache and download fresh gradle-3.3-all file

**step 4** 
Please keep your internet connection proper with good speed.
it will download all required file.
This issue gennerally comes when your internet connection is not stable or have slow sped. I am saying this as per error log given by AS.
Error:Failed to open zip file.

```
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

If everything else fails, an option is to use a local distribution of `gradle`.

[Download](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) a zipped version of Gradle.

unzip it and place it in a directory. Preferably `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle`

As at time of writing, I am using `gradle-3.4.1-bin`

Then, direct gradle to this directory:

`File > Settings > Gradle > use local gradle distribution`

[image]

Sync your project and you are good to go.

Note: Although it is recommended to use the default gradle wrapper, this option is fine.The only "problem" is you have to manually track updates etc

Answer (score 4):

for mac user just go to the `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` and delete all the folders there
for more explanation follow the detail below

- open finder
- Go -> `Go to Folder`
- type `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` and press enter
- delete all the folders in it
- now, restart android studio, it will download all the files again

Answer (score 3):

Just delete `gradle` folder , and let `android studio` **download** it again with click on `Sync now` !.

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve it:

1. Go to gradle-wrapper.properties from the "project" side menu
2. Change: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

After this studio should be able to download the correct zip file i.e. "gradle-3.3-all.zip".

If this does not help then you will have to make a few efforts:

1. Download the zip file manually from gradle-3.3-all.zip
2. Copy the zip file.
3. Reach the directory wherever your ".gradle" folder exists. It's usually in "C:\Users\user.gradle", if you are on windows.
4. Navigate to "wrapper" and then to "gradle-3.3-all".
5. Replace the zip file already there with the newly downloaded zip file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this case appear to me when try to open another project that I download it from github so I just change all gradle files in all project to the latest gradle build

1. build.gradle --> **module app** // compileSdkVersion and
   buildToolsVersion
2. build.gradle --> **project** // classpath
   'com.android.tools.build:gradle:currentVersion
3. build.gradle --> **library** is exist.
4. gradle-wrapper.properties -->  be accurate to check the
   **distributionUrl** is start with ***https not http***

all of this solve the problem for me ..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue 4 days ago and today I was able to solve it by changing the

`Compile Sdk Version` to `26`

`Target Sdk Version` to `26`

`Min Sdk Version` to `26`

`Build Tools Version` to `28`

by going to

```
    File > Project Structure >
```

[image]

[image]

What did not work::

1. deleting .gradle folder
2. downloading gradle with Android studio
3. downloading gradle manually
4. Updating Android studio

Answer (score 0):

I had different distributionUrl in two gradle-wrapper.properties inside my project