# How do I solve Gradle dependency cache may be corrupt in my newly downloaded Android studio 4.2

Tags: android, gradle-dependencies

I have tried several solutions like deleting the .gradle file and replacing it with another downloaded file but to no avail. Please I am currently using win7, 64 bit, 4g RAM, which android studio will be able to effectively work on this system type and give me the desired android studio experience that I need. Thanks

Comment: Please add more details like, which version of gradle-wrapper you're using or the gradle version? (Can be found on `gradle-wrapper.properties`/`build.gradle` project level)

Comment: Did you checked this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596215/how-to-fix-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-error-after-updating-andro/45990950 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network ?