# Gradle Dependancy cache may be crupt issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i download new android studio version 2.3.1 but having an issue i dont know how to deal with it can any one help me , Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mdp7.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39821915/3142192

Answer (score 1):

from this SO [Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network/42622353#42622353)

change distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties with this one.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into

> gragle/gradle-wrapper.properties

where you will find `distributionUrl` change its value to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

It will solve this issue.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Go To `File/Settings/Gradle` 
 uncheck offline work

and also check use default gradle wrapper(recommended)

Your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download gradle-3.3-all.zip from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

2.Decompress it, open the folder of ‘/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle’. Delete the old vsersion gradle and copy gradle-3.3 into ‘/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle’.
3. Open your project's 'gragle/gradle-wrapper.properties',change value

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

4.Close Android studio and restart it.

Comment: Thanks @Dale Che best solution i have no words to thanks, you save my day, i tried many answer but fixed my problem with your solution thanks