# Gradle project refresh failed (android)

Tags: android

! [Gradle refresh failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcUov.png)

I have this gradle issue when i upgrade my android studio, anyone able to help me?

Comment: What is the issue? Can you tell the error message?

Comment: what happened when you clicked on the provided solution?

Comment: I can't click on the provided solution, whenever i click on it, it just refreshes and the same old problem came back again. @TimCastelijns

Comment: @PriyaRajan I recently upgraded my android studio, i tried to load my previous project, but i got this error.

Comment: Can you post your dependencies? Is there any red line in your dependency?

Comment: Have you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101206/android-studio-re-download-dependencies-and-sync-project

Comment: Did you deleted your sdk folder as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your buildToolVersion should be same as your dependency version

Eg: Open the build.gradle(Module:app)

if your buildToolsVersion '25.0.2', then

```
compileSdkVersion 25

targetSdkVersion 25

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'

 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.2'

 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.2'
}
```

Finally, check your internet connection also.

Comment: Hope this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network

Comment: Always remember Gradle and Android studio updates are done seperately

Answer (score 0):

configure your SDK and update your gradle then rerun your project