# Import project in android studio- Version Control

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle, build

I'm Trying to import this project from GitHub but not able to as it shows the error

> "Re-download dependencies and sync project; Gradle's dependency cache
>   may be corrupt",

Project Link(Udacity)- [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud843-QuakeReport)
,Code in Gradle(Android Studio):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.quakereport"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Does any one have any Idea??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Re-download dependencies and sync project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101206/android-studio-re-download-dependencies-and-sync-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File->Project Structure then select Project and set

**Gradle version**

and

**Android Plugin Version**

to values identical to another project you must have recently created with Android Studio 2.2 and update SDK. Now sync gradle. Do *Build->Build Clean* with no issues. Then did *Run->Clean* and Rerun and project ran fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the values of Gradle version to 4.4 and Android Plugin version to 3.1.4

it is showing could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.